# Removing custom dialog instance

Tags: android, dialog

I had created one custom dialog method like -

```
Dialog dialog;
Dialog dialog;
public void callDialog() { if(dialog==null) {
    dialog = new Dialog(DemoActivity.this, R.style.ZoomInOut);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.show(); } }
```

Then i dismiss dialog using `dialog.dismiss()`;

but when i am calling dialog method second time then dialog == null it will gives me false.

It means `dialog.dismiss()` does not removes dialog object from memory? If no then what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize you dialog in onCreate and set the content layout.
then use this function for better result.

```
showDialog(){
if(dialog!=null && !dialog.isShowing())
dialog.show();
}

hideDialog(){
if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `dialog = null;` after `dialog.dismiss();`

OR

`dialog.dismiss();
 dialog = null;`

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss a dialog , it stops showing. The object itself does not become null.

If you want to check if dialog is showing , use this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29)